# Including one module into another with gradle in a multy project struture

Tags: java, gradle, module

I'm trying to build a jar from `example-project` that contains classes from `common` using Gradle. When I build the root project I get both jars but jar from `example-project` does not contain classes from `common`.

Here are my `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` of the root project.

```
rootProject.name = 'ExampleProject'

include 'common'
include 'example-project'
include 'example-api'
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0' apply false
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    group 'me.example'
    version '1.0.0'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {url = 'https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/'}
        maven {url = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/'}
        maven {url = 'https://repo.codemc.org/repository/maven-public/'}
        maven {url = 'https://repo.extendedclip.com/content/repositories/placeholderapi/'}
    }

    dependencies {
        compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.16.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
        compileOnly 'me.clip:placeholderapi:2.10.6'
        implementation 'org.bstats:bstats-bukkit:1.7'

        testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    }

}

project(':example-project') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':common')
    }
}
```

Comment: And what task did you use to create the jar? I see you applied the Shadow plugin; did you use the `shadowJar` task (see the [user guide](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/))?

Comment: @Slaw I didnt use it yet. i first wanted to make this part work. So its just added now but not in use.

Comment: The normal `jar` task does not package dependencies in the JAR file, even when the dependency is a sister project.

Comment: @Slaw so what exactly should i do to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you're lost. You already have the Shadow Plugin applied; that plugin's entire purpose is to create fat/uber JAR files so it seems you already understand what you need to do. In your case, executing `./gradlew :example-project:shadowJar` should work for you (that syntax executes the `shadowJar` task specifically on the `example-project` project). The plugin's user guide goes into more detail (I linked to it in my first comment).

Comment: @Slaw i just wasn't sure if thats the way i should go since i thought maybe there is another way without the use of the plugin. But i tried it with shadow jar and it worked i got all my needed classes in a single jar. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This can be closed referring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67947806/put-jar-output-from-one-module-into-another/75235358#75235358 probably