# Put jar output from one module into another

Tags: java, gradle

I have Gradle 7 project, there are two sub modules

```
 - Root
   - sub project A
   - sub project B
```

My goal is following:

1. When project A is build it creates a A.jar file.
2. When project B is build it creates a B.jar file that contains unexploded A.jar output from build of project A

To be more clear B.jar should look something like this

```
\META-INF
\my
  \package
    \tree
      SomeClassInsideBJar

\A.jar
```

```
URI aJarUri = someClassInsideBjar.getClassLaoder().getResource("A.jar");
```

Subproject A build  just fine, but i cannot figure out how to embed its jar into B.jar

According to another questions I should be able to get a reference to .jar output of a task by .archiveFile property

I tried this in B`s build file

```
jar {
    sourceSets.main.resources.includes = project(":A").getByName("build").archiveFile
}
```

But that ends with error

> No signature of method: build_62kfcng7dpn0plap6jwx8ojvt.jar() is
> applicable for argument types:
> (build_62kfcng7dpn0plap6jwx8ojvt$_run_closure2) values:
> [build_62kfcng7dpn0plap6jwx8ojvt$_run_closure2@be2d508]

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to include **classes and resources** project `A` to `B`

The module `B` should contain:

```
dependencies {
  // it must be compile only to prevent it to be exposed as a transitive dependency in the pom file
  compileOnly project(":A")
}

jar {
    from project(':A').sourceSets.main.output
}
```

Then you shall expect when you generate a jar with `jar` task inside the `B.jar` classes from module `A` right next to the classes from `B`, e.g. modules are merged.

Gradle 7.6.0

Answer (score -2):

If what you need to do is to reference the project A inside project B, then you can compile project A at the time of project B build time and add it as a dependency to the project B jar file.

include both projects in `settings.gradle` file in the root project.

```
include 'project A'
include 'project B'
```

then in the `build.gradle` file of project B add

```
dependencies{
   compile (':project A')
}
```

Comment: No, i need the unexploded A jar  inside B.jar.